# Access the authenticated user from other class (without SecurityContextHolder)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I want to implement mongodb auditing in my microservices and I did not know how to handle the authenticated user from the AuditorAware class.
in a monotholic application, we can handle the user with **SecurityContextHolder**. but in my case, **SecurityContextHolder** is only available in zuul microservice (where I manage security).
So i can't use this example of **AuditorAware** class.

```
class SpringSecurityAuditAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Long> {

@Override
public Optional<Long> getCurrentAuditor() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication == null ||
            !authentication.isAuthenticated() ||
            authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

    return Optional.ofNullable(userPrincipal.getId());
}
```

To pass authentication to the controllers of my microservices, I created this class which extract the token in each request, construct the authenticated user object, and inject it into the parameters of the methods of the controllers

```
class AuthenticationHandler : HandlerMethodArgumentResolver
{
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var tokenUtils : TokenUtils



    override fun supportsParameter(parameter : MethodParameter) : Boolean
    {
        return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(Authentication::class.java)
                && parameter.parameterType == AuthUser::class.java
                && (parameter.getParameterAnnotation(Authentication::class.java)?.required == true)
    }


    override fun resolveArgument(parameter : MethodParameter,mavContainer : ModelAndViewContainer?, webRequest : NativeWebRequest,binderFactory : WebDataBinderFactory?) : AuthUser
    {
        return try
        {
            val token : String? = tokenUtils.getTokenHeader(webRequest)

            tokenUtils.getUser(token!!)!!
        }
        catch (exception : Exception)
        {
            throw UnauthorizedException()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a clean method I can use to pass the AuthUser object created  in the AuthenticationHandler class from the AuditorAware class?

Comment: This is a good example for the proposition that your entire invocation context, including security principal, should be passed to your service methods.

Comment: @chrylis I found a solution, but I'm not too sure if it's good.
I have injected **HttpRequestServlette** into my **AuditorAware** class (since it can be accessed from any class). and in each request, after the validation of the security, I put the name and the id of the user in the headers of the request, and i extract them from **AuditorAware** class using the injcted **HttpRequestServlette** class.. is it a good idea?

Comment: No, it's not a good idea. You're hiding state in a custom manner. A very good guideline is to examine how difficult it will be to test your code; in this case, you'll require elaborate mocks of unrelated interfaces that have to be injected into second- or third-level dependencies. It would be much simpler across many dimensions to have Zuul forward the OAuth token onto each service independently.